# Segmentation fault copying to String array in node

Tags: c

I'm receiving a segmentation fault when attempting the following string copy:

The node definition:

```
typedef struct node {
    char *args[25];
    struct node *next;
} Node;
```

Then from main():

```
Node *node;
node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
copyArgs(args, node->args);
```

Then the invoked method:

```
void copyArgs(char **args, char **nodeArgs) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {
        strcpy(nodeArgs[i], args[i]);
    }
}
```

For some reason, though, I'm getting the following error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I understand there are other posts re: segmentation faults when using strcpy, but I was unable to find one specific to my issue. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

SOLUTION EDIT:
As was kindly pointed out, the for loop needed to be corrected as such:

```
for (i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {
    nodeArgs[i] = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    strcpy(nodeArgs[i], args[i]);
}
```

Thank you everyone for your patience.

Comment: Because `args[i]` is not allocated.

Comment: You allocate space for a `Node`, but the `args` member is uninitialized. You have some pointers, but they don't point anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *args[MAXLINE/2+1];` is array of char pointers !

Each pointer must have a allocated a memory space, before you could actually copy something into those.

`strcpy(nodeArgs[i], args[i]);` blindly copies on un-allocated space.

You'll have to allocate memory for each `args` too along with `Node`